# PHP Session issues, perhaps lost data?

Tags: session, php

I'm having some issues using sessions on my test website (Running it on WAMP server locally, using PHP php5.3.13) I have checked my php.ini to make sure that sessions are actually being saved, which they are:

```
C:\wamp\tmp
```

Basically, when the user logs in it shows, `Welcome back, .$username` so when I log in with the user "John", it shows this accordingly. Now, when I leave the login page and go back to it this sessions is somehow being lost. (And yes, I am using session_start at the top of every page).

Here is my code;

index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Codecall Tutorials - Secured Login with php5</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php include "header.php" ?>

         <div id="wrapper">
             <form method="post" action="">
             <h2>Log In</h2>
             <div id="underline"></div>
                 <ul>
                     <li>
                         <label for="usn">Username : </label>
                         <input type="text" maxlength="30" required autofocus name="username" />
                     </li>

                     <li>
                         <label for="passwd">Password : </label>
                         <input type="password" maxlength="30" required name="password" />
                     </li>
                     <li class="buttons">
                         <input type="submit" name="login" value="Log me in" class="xbutton" />
                            <input type="button" name="register" value="Forgot Password?" onclick="location.href='passrecover.php'" class="xbutton" />
                     </li>

                 </ul>
             </form>

            </div>

    </body>
</html>

<?php include "login.php" ?>
```

And my login.php page:

```
<?php 

if($_POST){

        if(empty($_POST['username']) && empty($_POST['password'])) {
            echo 'Please enter all fields';
        }else {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        if($password !== $password){
            echo 'Your password is wrong';
        }else {

            $db_name = 
            $db_user = 
            $db_pass = 

            $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX', // My bd details have been removed for this post, for security issues obviously
                array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true )
        );

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username,password from members WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username,password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($username, $password));

            if($stmt->rowCount() === 1 )
            {   
                $_SESSION['name']= $username;
                echo 'Welcome back '. $_SESSION['name'];
                //echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=usercp.php">';
            }else {
                echo 'Username or Password incorrect.';
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

?>

So, when I originally log in it shows the `$_SESSION['name'];`
 just fine, but when I move page and go back to it, it no longer shows it. (My other pages also have `session_start();` ) My original assumption was that my code was wrong, or that my php.ini file wasn't saving any data. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you aren't moving between subdomains? www.domain.com and just domain.com will not store the same session information.

Comment: The URL to my different pages is this http://localhost/PHP/Templates/Login/  then just the other pages in that directory

Comment: The reason it no longer shows is because when you go to another page, you aren't processing that block of code anymore. Because $_POST is empty on a regular page load, so you aren't echoing anything out. Try adding, `var_dump($_SESSION);` at the top of your page and then load something.

Comment: I was thinking it had something to do with this. Perhaps if I add an if statement stating, `if ($_SESSION === 1) { echo out my name} else {$_POST {}` would something like this function?

Comment: try this right after your `session_start();`,
`if(!empty($_SESSION['name'])) { echo "Hello {$_SESSION['name']}"; }`

Comment: Yes that works just fine. It was good to know that the session data wasn't being lost, instead it just had no where to go when the page had been changed. Thank you for this Tristan

Comment: Would you like to add that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: `if($password !== $password){` w00t? Instead of wrapping code in this if condition, try `//` instead ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it no longer shows is because when you go to another page, you aren't processing that block of code anymore. Because `$_POST` is empty on a regular page load, so you aren't echoing anything out. Try adding, `var_dump($_SESSION);` at the top of your page and then load something.

Try this right after your `session_start();`,

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['name'])) { 
   echo "Hello {$_SESSION['name']}"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add session_start() on your login.php too

Comment: Thought the same thing but `login.php` is included at the bottom of `index.php` so `session_start()` is visible to it too.

Comment: If I do this I get an error on my actual page stating it has already been initiated

Comment: `; Initialize session on request startup.
; http://php.net/session.auto-start
session.auto_start = 0`  Should this be set to 1?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're destroying the session somewhere in the script.